# Close Child Browser and Reload Parent Browser using C#

Tags: c#, browser, reload, using

I have a Browser A from which when a link button is clicked Browser B is opened. In Browser B I have a grid in which I have a "Add Link button".  In that Add Link button I am using OnClientClick for some Javascript Validation and OnClick for some submission. After OnClick If the submission is true passed I need to close that browser(B) and reload  the Parent Browser(A).

I CAN'T USE JAVASCRIPT OnClientClick event on LinkButton as I am using it already.  Is there any other way or else using C#, can I do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it worked finallly..  I modified the  JavaScript function for relaoding/refreshing the Parent Window from reload to "window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href" then it stopped from warning popup -- [image: Browser Reload Popup Warning]

I below line, it worked with out any pop up waring..
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "close", "window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;self.close();");

Thanks for your help & input..!!!

Answer (score 4):

C# does not run on the client side.

The only way to do it is through javascript.

You need to find some way to call it from javascript, just use a callback function or method to run once you have completed the rest of the work.

Edit:

You could always use a hidden field as well, set this on the postback using C#, then pick it up front end using javascript check for a particular value in there or something?!

or, use a script manager and let the c# call javascript through this.

This is another couple of methods you could use.

Comment: @msbyuva If you're using it already then assign a function to it and perform your logic in the function. Jimplode is correct, you can only do it with javascript.

Comment: @Chevex  thanks for the reply. I haven't worked earlier with call back functions. I will check that. Thank You..!!

Comment: You can use Silverlight as well

Comment: Thanks for the direction Jimplode, Chevex, I got it..!!

Comment: I was able to do it by using the onbeforeunload event on the Formload and called that from pageload.  I wonder that for some reasons I was unable to do it with using ScriptManager to call JavaScript : Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "close", "<script language=javascript>window.opener.location.reload(true);self.close();</script>");